# Facebook mention tags not possible before user has commented her own post? [Bug?]

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Comments with inline mention tags of users, we know that it's possible to send them through the API to post on pages using the syntax:

@[USERID:USERNAME]

However, this seems only possible when mentioning a user who have made a comment herself to that post. It is, from what I can see, not possible to post a comment with a mention tag of user who wrote the post you're actually commenting - unless that user first comments her own post.

This seems, in short, really weird. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.